# Display error if element in array have 0 value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have an array in javascript using map function. it collect data from a loop drop down. i just want to ask how to check if array have 0 then display error message. "One of the data not selected"

the array code :

```
var self_assess_check = $("select[name='self_assess[]'] option:selected").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
            }).get();

             alert(self_assess_check);
```

if i alert the array `alert(self_assess_check);` it produce : 1,0,2,-,-,5,0

how can i make if condition to check if whole array have 0 value then show error message

what i made:

```
if ((self_assess_check) == "0"){


        alert("One of the data not selected");
             return false; 

             }else{
             var r=confirm("Make sure all answer is correct. Once Submit it cannot be changed");
                if (r==true){



                }else{

                return false;              
               }


             }
```

i think my if condition not correct since it will go to else and skip if.tq

Comment: hye Phil, thanks for the comment.. got the solution already..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
if ($.inArray('0', self_assess_check) != -1) {
    alert("One of the data not selected");
    return false;
} else {
    var r = confirm("Make sure all answer is correct. Once Submit it cannot be changed");
    if (r == true) {
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

*Note: [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is not used since IE8 might have to be supported.*

Comment: tq arun, the code works but i have lilte problem. if i select the dropdown according to queue (dropdown 1,2,3) the code not works. But if i select dropdown randomly (dropdown 3,2,1) the code work perfect. it seem like the condition only validate first element and ignore others which have 0 value in it. it not checking whole array just first element. if first array 0 the code working.. example array : 0,4,2,0 (works) array : 1,0,0,1 (not work)

Comment: @airi there was a bug in the code.. fixed now.. you need to check `$.inArray('0', self_assess_check) == -1`

Comment: if the array : 1,1,1,1 it not work. it not go to else but display "One of the data not selected"

Comment: @airi again a silly mistake.. if there is a `0` then the index won't be -1 else it will be -1 so you need to test `!= -1` to show the errro msg

Comment: cool.. now works perfectly.. thanks  Arun P Johny for your help.. really appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check Array as below code.
`function isUndefined(targetO){
    return (targetO == 'undefined' || targetO == undefined);
}  if(!isUndefined(self_assess_check){ if(self_assess_check.length!=0){alert("Array contain values"); }}`

This will work.

Comment: hye neel dhara.. thanks for the solution.. got solution already.. :)